# Exporting Correlation Matrix (from function)

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, numpy, matplotlib

I'm interested in exporting a correlation matrix to csv. I've tried using the to.csv functionality, but my matrix is obtained from a function and I get an "object has no attribute 'to_csv'" error. I appreciate any guidance. Code is below.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm as cm

def correlation_matrix(df):

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
    cmap = cm.get_cmap('jet', 30)
    cax = ax1.imshow(df.corr(), interpolation="nearest", cmap=cmap)
    ax1.grid(True)
    plt.title('Feature Correlation')
    labels = None
    # Add colorbar, and make sure to specify tick locations to match desired ticklabels.
    cbar = fig.colorbar(cax, ticks=[-1.1, -0.8, -0.6, -0.4, -0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6,.8,1])
    plt.show()

correlation_matrix(pd.DataFrame(np.c_[Xs,Y]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the matrix obtained from your function rather,

It looks like [`correlation` is a DataFrame too](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html), so you can simply use [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
correlation_df(within your function itself).to_csv("C:\destinationfolder\file.csv")
```

Comment: Don't understand. Do you mean to not use the correlation function, or to export to csv from within it?

Comment: What I mean is when using `df.corr()` it returns a dataframe itself which can easily be exported to different extensions.. you are using numpy to do the same, that's why a matrix,.also you can directly plot Correlation matrices, there are inbuilt functions to do the same or just use the sns.heatmap.. Let me know if I am not clear again